# how to rearrange order of columns from other dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe columns in pandas

```
 df1
 Index(['Income','Age','Gender'])

 df2
 Index(['Age','Gender','Income'])
```

I want to reorder the column order of `df2`as per `df1` How can I do it in pandas? In R I can easily do it with `df2[names(df1)]`

Comment: I want to reorder the columns, this will rename the columns,I suppose.

Comment: You're right, my bad

Comment: Looks like you can do `df2 = df2[df1.columns]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-order the columns based on another dataframe with the same columns but different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493255/how-to-re-order-the-columns-based-on-another-dataframe-with-the-same-columns-but)